# How to split array by duplicate values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects, and I have to split it by duplicate values on `index` property. For a sample array of objects like the next one:

```
[
  {index: 0, value: 3},
  {index: 0, value: 3},
  {index: 0, value: 3},
  {index: 1, value: 3},
  {index: 1, value: 3},
  {index: 2, value: 3},
  {index: 2, value: 3}
]
```

The expected result should be:

```
{
  0: [
    {index: 0, value: 3},
    {index: 0, value: 3},
    {index: 0, value: 3}
  ],
  1: [
    {index: 1, value: 3},
    {index: 1, value: 3}          
  ],
  2: [
    {index: 2, value: 3},
    {index: 2, value: 3}
  ]
}
```

Comment: You claim you need to split on duplicate values, but it looks like you're splitting on duplicate indices. Also, why bother using an object with ascending numerical keys from 0 to `n`? An array seems more appropriate for the task. Please clarify your intent and post what you've attempted so far.

Answer (score 5):

Here you have one solution using [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const input = [
  {index: 0, value: 3},
  {index: 0, value: 3},
  {index: 0, value: 3},
  {index: 1, value: 3},
  {index: 1, value: 3},
  {index: 2, value: 3},
  {index: 2, value: 3},
  {index: 0, value: 3}
];

let obj = input.reduce((res, curr) =>
{
    if (res[curr.index])
        res[curr.index].push(curr);
    else
        Object.assign(res, {[curr.index]: [curr]});

    return res;
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

The previous example will make groups of all objects with equal `index` property. However, if you are looking to separate the objects by streaks that have equal `indexes` you can do this:

```js
const input = [
  {index: 0, value: 3},
  {index: 0, value: 3},
  {index: 0, value: 3},
  {index: 1, value: 3},
  {index: 1, value: 3},
  {index: 2, value: 3},
  {index: 2, value: 3},
  {index: 0, value: 3},
  {index: 0, value: 3},
  {index: 0, value: 3},
  {index: 2, value: 3},
  {index: 2, value: 3}
];

let obj = input.reduce((res, curr) =>
{
    if (curr.index === res.last)
    {
        res.r[res.idx - 1].push(curr);
        return res;
    }

    Object.assign(res.r, {[res.idx]: [curr]});
    res.last = curr.index;
    res.idx++;
    return res;

}, {r: {}, idx: 0, last: null});

console.log(obj.r);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get this:

```js
const input=[{index:0,value:3},{index:0,value:3},{index:0,value:3},{index:1,value:3},{index:1,value:3},{index:2,value:3},{index:2,value:3}]

/* If index exists in the accumulator object, use that.
  else, create the index and point to an empty array
  push the item in context to the array
*/
const output = input.reduce((acc, v) => {
  acc[v.index] = acc[v.index] || [];
  acc[v.index].push(v);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(output)
```

Here's a short version:

```js
const input=[{index:0,value:3},{index:0,value:3},{index:0,value:3},{index:1,value:3},{index:1,value:3},{index:2,value:3},{index:2,value:3}]

const output = input.reduce((a,v) => ((a[v.index] = a[v.index] || []).push(v), a), {});

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Very clean technique. Note, it can create a sparse array though.

Comment: @HarryRiley The accumulator is an object with numerical indices. It's not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Do a simple `reduce` operation:

```js
const data = [{
    index: 0,
    value: 3
  },
  {
    index: 0,
    value: 3
  },
  {
    index: 0,
    value: 3
  },
  {
    index: 1,
    value: 3
  },
  {
    index: 1,
    value: 3
  },
  {
    index: 2,
    value: 3
  }, {
    index: 2,
    value: 3
  }
];

const modified = data.reduce((val, acc) => {
  if (acc[val.index]) {
    acc[val.index].push(val);
  } else {
    acc[val.index] = [{
      index: [val.index],
      value: [val.value]
    }];
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(modified);
```

Comment: I am getting only the last part of the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple `for` loop

```js
const input = [
    {index: 0, value: 3},
    {index: 0, value: 3},
    {index: 0, value: 3},
    {index: 1, value: 3},
    {index: 1, value: 3},
    {index: 2, value: 3},
    {index: 2, value: 3}
];

const newArray = {}
for(var i of input) {
  if(newArray[i.index]) {
    newArray[i.index].push(i)
  } else {
    newArray[i.index] = [i]
  }
}

console.log(newArray)
```